# Too many arguments for public inline fun println(): Unit defined in kotlin.io

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, printing, println

I am trying to make a simple program that let you add just two numbers (just learning basics) and i just "fell" to this problem:

> GODCalculator.kt: (18, 15):Too many arguments for public inline fun
> println(): Unit defined in kotlin.io

I tried to find some anwsers on internet, but didn't find excatly what i wanted to...
nothing solved my issue

```
fun addition(){
println("So please insert two numbers, the program i mean the god will solve your math problem.")
print("Number #1: "); val z = readLine()!!.toInt()
print("\n")
print("Number #2: "); val c = readLine()!!.toInt()
val v = c+z
println(z," + " ,c, " = ",v)
```

Problem with:
**println(z," + " ,c, " = ",v)**

but i also tried with "+" edition like this:
**println(z+" + "+c+" = "+v)**

both didn't work :/

I use:
IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition, but I don't think it matters anyway
*I am learning Kotlin on console, because when i tried to start use Android Studio i just got scared how many i have to know...*

Edit:
Thanks to lpizzinidev.
His anwser totally fixed my issue...
The correct way is: `println("$z + $c = $v")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use string interpolation:

```
println("$z + $c = $v")
```

If you want to use string concatenation you should first convert the integers to a string with `.toString()`:

```
println(z.toString() + " + " + c.toString() + " = " + v.toString())
```

The former approach is more verbose.